# WebRequest.GetResponse() throwing NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net

When making a web request, after writing data to the server, calling `GetResponse()` is throwing a `NullReferenceException`. This doesn't happen when I step through the code (i.e.: via F10), but does when I Continue in Debug (i.e.: via F5).

```
Using dataStream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        Dim responseDoc As String = String.Empty

        Using response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse) ' NullReferenceException Here
            Dim responseStream As IO.Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
            Dim readStream As New System.IO.StreamReader(responseStream, encoding)
            responseDoc = readStream.ReadToEnd()
        End Using
End Using
```

Comment: Seems like you try to get a response without specifically saying you want to send the request. Write doesn't always send the data right away. Check the [sample code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx).

Comment: @the_lotus Really? That's the first time I've heard/seen that. How can I explicitly make it send it now? I would assume, since it's a synchronous call, it would be done automatically.

Comment: Try closing the dataStream before opening a response.

Comment: I actually tried that before posting. Same issue.